# How To Can I Restrict The User From Entering More Than 1 Digit In Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In,

```
a=int(input("Enter A Integer: "))
```

How Can I Prevent The User From Entering More Than 4 Digits In This Input

Comment: After user input their number,check its length.If its length is larger than 4,then remind user to input again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent user from entering as many digits he want, but you can always check the size, and prompt the user to reenter if it exceeds it.

```
a=10001
while a > 9999 :
    a = int(input("Enter A Integer less than 9999: "))
```

Of course you would need exception handling if he passes a string instead of number.